# oracle SUBSTR date duration

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

when i do query SUBSTR(e.updatetime - s.updatetime, 1,30) i will get result below
+000000001 05:06:47.388000

can this save in java.util.Date? or which java class should i use other than String to ease me retrieve day,minutes,hours...

p/s: e.updatetime is timestamp type

Comment: SUBSTR expects a string as its first parameter, however you're passing an interval. Therefore it's doing an implicit data type conversion for you - it's better to do an explicit data type conversion using TO_CHAR. It's probably better to use Gary's suggestion and avoid any conversion to string at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the separate fields, then join them up as you want.

```
select extract (day from (time_b-time_a)), 
       extract (hour from (time_b-time_a)), 
       extract (minute from (time_b-time_a)), 
       extract (second from (time_b-time_a)) 
from ....;
```

Answer (score 1):

this snippet might be helpful too:

```
select ...,  
    extract (day    from (j.finished_date - j.started_date)) * 86000 + 
    extract (hour   from (j.finished_date - j.started_date)) * 3600  +
    extract (minute from (j.finished_date - j.started_date)) * 60 +
    extract (second from (j.finished_date - j.started_date)) as "duration"
```